# I want to copy all of collection 2 as sub objects into collection 1 on matching fields

Tags: mongodb, collections, merge

Data Description
*Meters collection* has Location, Meter_Name etc...
*MeterTags collection* has Location, Meter_Name, and other fields...

*Meters Collection Example* has
Location: 'Loc1', MeterName: 'M1'....other fields

*MeterTags Example has:*
Location: 'Loc1', MeterName: 'M1', Address: '470901',... other fields
Location: 'Loc1', MeterName: 'M1', Address: '470902',... other fields
Location: 'Loc1', MeterName: 'M1', Address: '470903',... other fields

I want to put each meterTags document with matching Location and  Metername into the matching document in Meters.
So I guess the result document would be

```
{  
Location: 'Loc1',  
MeterName: "M1",  
MeterTags: [{Location: 'Loc1',MeterName:'M1',Address: '47091'},  
{Location: 'Loc1',MeterName:'M1',Address:'47092'}....]
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I dont really need to repeat the Location and Metername fields in my tags array in the new collection. So if the solution could show me how to project only the fields i want that would be helpful.

Comment: Please go to Help and edit your question

Comment: Done, sorry for not understanding the system